# How to simulate anchor tag hover and click on a div

Tags: jquery

How do you initiate a hover pointer and a click function to another web page on a div with jquery?

So, my div class is `.ei-title`:

```
$('.ei-title').click(function() {
   /* load the page 'http://google.com' in the same window */
});
```

Also, when you hover over the div element, it should show a pointer

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the `div` to behave like an `<a href>`. If so, here's how:
CSS for the cursor:

```
div.ei-title {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.ei-title').click(function(){
  location = 'http://www.google.com'
})
```

Comment: thank you Abraham, appreciate. Aren't you missing a ; at the end of the function (both after 'href' and {)... )?

Comment: In Javascript, you don't *need* semicolons. I know you *should* use them, but I usually don't. The code will work fine with or without semicolons.

Comment: another thing, the cursor: pointer does not work in chrome(I have the latest)...any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, jQuery is Javascript, so Javascript syntax applies to jQuery too. About the cursor: works for me, really quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c2qFy/

Comment: yeah thanks, wasn't sure though...and yes, the cursor works in jsfiddle, although on my website, the div is in a jquery slider, it works in FF and IE, just not in IE...weird

Comment: If you want me to take a look in IE, post the URL to your website and I'll check.

Comment: Seems to work OK on the website for me, except for the tooltip thingys that keep popping up.

Comment: No the div elements I'm referring to are the big titles inside the images...not the a links at the bottom with the popups

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.ei-title').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    window.location = 'http://www.google.com';   
});
```

Although really the css should be moved out into the stylesheet and not applied via javascript.

Comment: thank you for your answer...the cursor: pointer does not work in chrome(I have the latest)...any suggestions?

Comment: what does event.preventDefault(); and event.stopImmediatePropagation() do?

Comment: They both stop the default action of an event and stop it bubbling up - in your case using it on a div wouldn't do anything as div's have no default actions. However it's there in case you wanted to apply it to something that did, like an anchor tag.

Comment: The chrome thing could be a bug with Chrome itself: [link]http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=80339